# Security HTTP Response Headers

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to secure my http response header.

From what I do previously in nodejs, I would used helmet and a bit of manual configuration to do the job.

I researched on Spring as well and I came out with this table.

So my main question is:

Is there a need for me to handle stuff like X-Powered-By-Header in Spring?
Meaning for me to block `X-Powered-By-Header`, `ieNoOpen` in Spring?

[image: Spring VS Nodejs]

Comment: Spring Boot cannot remove the `X-Powered-By` as that is written by the app-server. Most app servers though have a property to disable this (which with an embedded server, is quite easy to setup, although I believe that Tomcat already disabled this by default).

Answer (score 0):

`X-Powered-By` is a non-standard HTTP header which is provided by the app server. Normally you will disable default HTTP headers using this configuration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
      // ...
     .headers().disable();
}
```

But since `X-Powered-By` is a non-standard API this code won't disable this header from your app server. You can configure your app-server to disable this header though.

> Is there a need to handle stuff like X-Powered-By-Header in Spring?

Well if you want to then you possibly can override the header like this

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Powered-By-Header","Express"))
     ....
}
```

Comment: i think you got my question wrong. I am asking if i need to do more to config spring security to block `X-Powered-By-Header` for example.

Comment: Yes. If you want to configure spring security to block or change `X-Powered-By-Header` then you need to do some manual configuration, just you had to do in Helmet. The configuration you have to do is added in the code.

Comment: i was searching the spring documentation and i don't see anything about blocking `X-Powered-By-Header`.

Comment: Yes because it is a non-standard header. But you can create custom header which in turn will actually override the x-powered-by header coming from server. Custom header can be created like [this](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/headers.html#headers-static)

Comment: Ok. I get what you meant. So in this case, where I do not need `X-Powered-By-Header` to show up in request header, I actually do not need to do anything. Am I right?

Comment: Umm no. Your spring app is not sending the header, the server where your app is hosted at is. So no, by doing nothing spring security will not stop the server from sending the header. You need to send custom header from your spring app which will override your app server header.